# Pass predefined CSS Style to getElementsbyName?

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementsbyname

This is probably a really easy question but I used google and the search function without digging up anything that worked for me.

I'm using a script that changes the font of a `<div>` using the `getElementsByName()` function on mouseover and change again when you pull the mouse away, this works as intended but I've rewrote some code of this little project and now the font used is dependent on the OS (see css styling) - which means I can't pass back "static" text properties.

Basically I need the else junction of the script to apply the CSS styling of `class="japanese large pos"` or its previous state if that is cleaner/more efficient, I left out the CSS below since it's not really relevant. Fiddle Demo here (including CSS): http://jsfiddle.net/ua5VS/

Thank you for the help!

This is the script:

```js
function toggleFont()
{
  var _font = document.getElementsByName('target')[0].style.fontFamily;
  if(_font != 'KanjiStrokeOrders') {
    document.getElementsByName('target')[0].style.fontFamily = 'KanjiStrokeOrders';
    document.getElementsByName('target')[0].style.fontSize = '112px';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementsByName('target')[0].style.fontFamily = 'MS Mincho';
    document.getElementsByName('target')[0].style.fontSize = '150px';
  }
}
```

HTML

```html
 <div class="back">
  <span class="japanese large pos" name="target">
   <a onmouseover="toggleFont();" onmouseout="toggleFont();">Modified text</a>
  </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: I know, I could swear I tagged it as javascript. Thanks for the headsup.

Comment: Why not just have toggleFont change CSS class names?

Comment: Like I said this is probably an easy question, so I define another class for the switchfont and do `document.getElementsByName('target').className = "japanese otherfont pos";` right?

Comment: Yes. You can also do the same with .japanese.large.pos:hover { ... } and forget all the JS mouse stuff.

Comment: Hello and thanks again, I messed around a bit and the :hover selector really seems to be a much more elegant solution. Sorry for this useless question! I'm simply using `#target:hover{...};` and assign that ID where needed.